# How to find data in string?

Tags: python, python-re

How to find name, id, type in string using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

```
string = "Wacom Bamboo Connect Pen stylus   id: 15  type: STYLUS"
```

Expected Result:`("Wacom Bamboo Connect Pen stylus", 15, "STYLUS")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall). The regex:
`r'^(.*\S)\s+id:\s*(\d+)\s+type:\s*(.+)'` means:
`^` : start of the string.
`.*` :any character, repeated 0 or more times.
`\S` : non-whitespace character.
`\s+` : whitespace character, repeated 1 or more times.
`\d+` : any digit, repeated 1 or more times.
`(PATTERN)` : capture the patterns and return it. Here we capture 3 patterns.

```
import re

string = "Wacom Bamboo Connect Pen stylus   id: 15  type: STYLUS"

lst = re.findall(r'^(.*\S)\s+id:\s*(\d+)\s+type:\s*(.+)', string)

# The first match (list element) is a tuple. Extract it:
lst = list(lst[0])
lst[1] = int(lst[1])
print(lst)
# ['Wacom Bamboo Connect Pen stylus', 15, 'STYLUS']
```

Comment: Why `findall` and not `search`?

Comment: @CrazyChucky: Heck, if they're processing line by line, odds are they want `.match` or even `.fullmatch`.

Answer (score 0):

To match the **first string** before id you need:

```
.*(?=(id:))
```

To match the **id** you need:

```
(?<=id:.*)(\d*)(?=.*type)
```

To match the **type** you need:

```
(?<=type:.*)(\w+)
```

I would suggest you have a look at [lookaheads and lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/7177937).

Comment: Uh... `^[^id]*` matches any run of characters starting from the beginning of the string, consisting solely of characters that are neither `i` nor `d`. This technically works for the OP's specific example (before `id`, there are no `i`s or `d`s), but I suspect the inputs in general aren't that restrictive (`"Apple iPod  id: 21 type: Player"` is going to fail).

Comment: Right, that is a major flaw, I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!